# need some advices when making a streaming application

Tags: android

I'm developing an app on android that can play videos streamed from a server (my PC) likes youtube. I'm new to this and I need some advices to get a right approach.
First, my app on android should have the ability to seek to a position that have been played. So, in the server side (my PC), what streaming server should I use?
Do I need to combine the streaming packets into a temporary file and play on this file in order to get seek-back?